# Windows service created to shut down computer is not working when computer is locked

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a Windows service in C# to shut down the computer.

The service works fine when the computer is not locked (Ctrl + Alt + Del).

But some how it doesn't shut down when my computer is locked.

```
// call
DoExitWin(EWX_SHUTDOWN);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct TokPriv1Luid
{
    public int Count;
    public long Luid;
    public int Attr;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
    ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(int flg, int rea);

internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
internal const string SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME = "SeShutdownPrivilege";
internal const int EWX_LOGOFF = 0x00000000;
internal const int EWX_SHUTDOWN = 0x00000001;
internal const int EWX_REBOOT = 0x00000002;
internal const int EWX_FORCE = 0x00000004;
internal const int EWX_POWEROFF = 0x00000008;
internal const int EWX_FORCEIFHUNG = 0x00000010;

private static void DoExitWin(int flg)
{
    bool ok;
    TokPriv1Luid tp;
    IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
    ok = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
    tp.Count = 1;
    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    ok = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, ref tp.Luid);
    ok = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
    ok = ExitWindowsEx(flg, 0);
}
```

***UPDATE:***

Based on help from Chris Haas I am trying to find which call returns an error based on the value of `ok`:

```
ok = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); //error 87 ok return true 
ok = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, ref tp.Luid); 
error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); //error 997 ok return true rest of ok true with zero error code

ok = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
ok = ExitWindowsEx(flg, 0); //This mean error in ok
```

But `ok` returns true all the time.

Comment: Is the service running under the user account?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing its a permission issue but I don't know that definitely. One very important thing is that you are throwing away potential errors. You keep setting the `ok` variable but you never check it. This would probably tell you where there's a problem

**EDIT**

Also, I think you actually want to pass `EWX_SHUTDOWN | EWX_POWEROFF`

**EDIT 2**

If you get an error you should call [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx)

**EDIT 3**

You don't have to call GetLastError every time, just if `ok` is false:

```
int error;
ok = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
if(!ok){
    error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new ApplicationException('Error : ' + error);
}
tp.Count = 1;
tp.Luid = 0;
tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
ok = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, ref tp.Luid);
if(!ok){
    error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new ApplicationException('Error : ' + error);
}
ok = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
if(!ok){
    error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new ApplicationException('Error : ' + error);
}
ok = ExitWindowsEx(flg, 0);
if(!ok){
    error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new ApplicationException('Error : ' + error);
}
```

Comment: Not throwing any error. WIndows service works fine when computer is not locked. even tried it in windows application to for debugging.

Comment: @Rohit, I don't know your skill level so I apologize if you've checked this already. Win32 functions don't throw errors, they return non-zero values instead. You then call `GetLastError()` to determine what the error actually is. So just because you don't get an exception doesn't mean there's no errors. Check the value of `ok` at every step and if its false call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().

Comment: ok = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); //error 87 ok return true
ok = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, ref tp.Luid);
error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); //error 997 ok return true
rest of ok true with zero error code

Comment: Sorry, I was backwards, Win32 functions return non-zero for success, 0 for failure.

Comment: This mean error in ok = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
ok = ExitWindowsEx(flg, 0);

Comment: But all the time ok return true

Answer (score 2):

Use instead
[InitiateSystemShutdownEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See the comments regarding the parameters, you can force a shutdown if the machine is locked.

EDIT: I remember I used it some time ago. There's a specific comment in MSDN:

*Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:  If the computer is locked and the bForceAppsClosed parameter is FALSE, the last error code is ERROR_MACHINE_LOCKED. If the system is not ready to handle the request, the last error code is ERROR_NOT_READY. The application should wait a short while and retry the call. For example, the system can be unready to initiate a shutdown, and return ERROR_NOT_READY, if the shutdown request comes at the same time a user tries to log onto the system. In this case, the application should wait a short while and retry the call.*

Answer (score 0):

Windows service require permission of the user account in which it is installed. you can

**edit this permission by right clicking and selecting Logon** after navigating to

**AdministartiveTools->service->yourService.** Usually this will be set to "LOCAL SERVICE",

try giving the credentials of the account in which your service is running.

```
Please cross check whether you have done the following steps during windows service creation:

1.After creating the windows service project go to the service class's design view(just double click the service1.cs class).

2.In the design view right click and select Add Installer. This will create an Installer class named ProjectInstaller.cs. With out ProjectInstaller.cs or any error in configuring ProjectInstaller.cs may result in non-showing of the service in service console.

3.Go to the design view of ProjectInstaller.cs you will find two installers there->

 a.**ServiceInstaller1**

    b.**ServiceProcessInstaller1**  
4.Right click ServiceInstaller1 and go to the properties tab

    a.Edit the ServiceName with the name you want to 
      see your service in the service console.

    b.Change the **StartType** to **Automatic**.
5.Right click ServiceProcessInstaller1 and go to the properties tab

    a.Change the account to **LocalService**

    6. Save and try it.
```

Hope this will help you........